# How to fix JSON output for consumption by jquery Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to get JSON out of a webforms.cs page to .aspx page. It's relatively easy to do with JSONResult in MVC but it seems to be a pain with webforms.

So I have [WebMethod] function in my cs file like below.

This method is returning really weird json.

Fiddler's raw result looks like below.

{"d":"[[{\"name\":\"Label1\",\"y\":28....

Is there something like JsonResult for webforms? I guess since method return is of type string it's messing up the result and I don't know why it's coming up as array inside array and with name d.

I need this in [{name: "Label1", "y":28},{...] format.

How do i get it in this format?

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetData()
    {

        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();


        var myTable= DataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>(1) == 2018)
        .Select(x => new[]
        {
            new { name = "LABEl 1", y = x[2] },
            new { name = "Label 2", y = x[3] },




        });



        String export= json.Serialize(myTable);
        return export;


    }
```

Comment: Are you open to using a 3rd party library that you can easily add through the Nuget package manager?

Comment: Yes adding a library will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily convert it back to json inside success method of your Ajax call using

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response.d);
```

Comment: I know but I was just confused about array within array and what caused it to be named "d".